# Django Celery Eventlet - Getting "No address found" error

Tags: python, django, celery, eventlet

I am currently using celery default prefork for concurrency and I want to use Eventlet.

I tried to install Eventlet and used it for concurrency, but I am getting following error:

```
[2017-01-01 04:11:14,233: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://application:**@rabbit:5672//: [Errno -2] No address found.
```

But it is working good with default prefork and I could execute jobs async.

I am currently using django 1.10 and Celery 4.0.1

```
 -------------- celery@worker v4.0.1 (latentcall)
---- **** ----- 
--- * ***  * -- Linux-4.4.0-57-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial 2017-01-01 03:59:11
-- * - **** --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         fivefrets:0x7f97ca281a58
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://fivefrets:**@rabbit:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 10 (eventlet)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
            .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
```

can anyone help please, I could not get the answers googling.

Please us me know, if anyone have any questions.

Not sure what I am missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"No address found" looks like an error with DNS resolution. If you can resolve the address of your rabbitmq server, the problem may lie with Eventlet.

If you're using Eventlet 0.20.0, it looks like that might break DNS resolution. See: https://github.com/nameko/nameko/issues/392

If that's the case, maybe you can use a different version of eventlet with something like `pip install --upgrade eventlet==0.19.0` or `pip install --upgrade eventlet==0.20.1`.

Comment: Thank you..! resolution in https://github.com/nameko/nameko/issues/392 pip install -U https://github.com/eventlet/eventlet/archive/f266be30f5c3ff1889e9ac3f0bad698a49d40e99.zip

Comment: it worked. thanks for pointing me to the correct issue https://github.com/nameko/nameko/issues/392

Comment: Please change it to `eventlet==0.20.1`

Answer (score 0):

If you hit that error with `eventlet==0.20.0`, then it means you have malformed configuration. `/etc/resolv.conf` with `search domain` but you're issuing a relative hostname `rabbit` for which proper DNS resolution must attempt only `rabbit.domain` query to nameservers.

Proper solution options:

- introduce `.local` domain to your network, change resolv.conf, DNS records and application configs to `rabbit.local`. All things considered, this is the best way.
- remove `search` line from `/etc/resolv.conf`
- add trailing dot to single level hostnames in application configs `rabbit.` - that makes fully qualified hostname that is always resolved correctly

For less than perfect way, upgrade `eventlet>=0.20.1` it contains patch that attempts top level queries as if they were fully qualified (in this case `rabbit.`)